# convert an ISO8601 timestamp with C code

Tags: c

I'm trying to convert time from an ISO8601 timestamp.

I want to remove "T" from timestamp
exemple :

```
"0001-01-01T17:45:33" --> "0001-01-01 17:45:33"
```

this conversion is useful to convert  timestamp to epoch time

Comment: You've already asked this question here, in the same kind of structure, with no C code whatsoever. Publish your code - where is your input string allocated, and where do you want to write the output string?

Comment: please read carefully the question is not the same !!!!!!!!!

Comment: So here is an answer that is as technically detailed as your question: Scan the input string from left to right, and replace every occurrence of a `T` character or a `-` character with a space character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I teste with this code, it works fine for me

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char string[] = {"0001-01-01T17:45:33\0"};

    char *temp;

    temp = strchr(string, 'T') ;
    *temp= ' ';
    printf("%s\n", temp);
    printf("%s\n", string);
}
```

Comment: First of all, publish that in the question, not as a separate answer. Second, if it works fine, then what's the question to begin with?

Comment: at the first time I don't have the response for that, when any body don't want to answer I search that in other forum

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at

```
 char *strptime(const char *s, const char *format, struct tm *tm);
```

from `time.h` ?

For example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define __USE_XOPEN
#include<time.h>

int main(){
    char newtime[100];
    const char *time="0001-01-01T17:45:33";
    struct tm tm_;

    strptime(time,"%FT%T",&tm_);

    strftime(newtime,100,"%F %T",&tm_);

    printf("%s\n",newtime);
    printf("Epoch time:%d\n",(int)mktime(&tm_));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1-01-01 17:45:33
Epoch time:-1
```

Comment: when the timestamp contain 'T', it makes a problem !

Comment: mktime returns -1, because the input date is before the epoch started